# Nodejs Obtener valor de una funcion dentro de un variable

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ibm-bluemix

Amigos en tengo un situación que me pasa mucho en node , tengo una funcion que requiere de ciertos parametros para poder ejecutarse , una forma de obtener uno de estos parametros es con otra función así que quisiera obtener el valor de esta función detro de una variable, pero cuando lo paso e imprimo a consola los parametros me da un objeto o una promesa pendiente.
Esto es lo que tengo

```
  var session =  service.createSession({
  assistantId:"e41c876f-3e71-4c27-a58f-2744227d8d1f",
  })
  .then(res => {
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
    return res.result.session_id;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  app.post('/conversation/', async (req, res) => {
  const { text, context = {} } = req.body;

  const params = {
    input: { text },
    workspace_id: "****-****-****-****-****",
    assistantId:"****-****-****-****-****",
    sessionId: session,
    context,
  };

  console.log(params);

});
```

Y de respuesta obtengo esto

```
    Running on port 3000
{ input: { text: undefined },
  workspace_id: '****-****-****-****-****',
  assistantId: '****-****-****-****-****',
  sessionId: Promise { '****-****-****-****-****' },
  context: {} }
```

Alguien sabe como puedo obtener el valor que quiero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar otra sintaxis para manejar promesas y en este caso hará tu código más legible y comprenderás más fácilmente el manejo de promesas, lo que sucede es que cuando tu función realiza tareas asíncronas esta siempre retornará una promesa, por lo tanto tienes que esperar a su ejecución. La sintaxis que te comento es una alternativa al `.then()` y `.catch()`, esta es `async` y `await`.

[Acá](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-async-await-and-promises-explained-like-youre-five-years-old-61733751e9a5) puedes ver más información sobre el uso de esta sintaxis.

Mi propuesta usando estos conceptos es:

```
var session = service.createSession({
  assistantId: "e41c876f-3e71-4c27-a58f-2744227d8d1f",
});

app.post('/conversation/', async (req, res) => {
  const { text, context = {} } = req.body;

  try {
    const sessionRes = await session;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  const params = {
    input: { text },
    workspace_id: "****-****-****-****-****",
    assistantId: "****-****-****-****-****",
    sessionId: sessionRes.result.session_id,
    context,
  };

  console.log(params);
});
```

Como recomendación, cuando utilices el `await` es buena práctica envolverlo en un `try / catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Con un `await session` lo podrías solucionar, ejemplo:

```js
var session = new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let session = {session_id: "123456"};
        r(session.session_id)
    }, 1000);
});


async function post(){//<-- solo va a funcionar dentro de async

    const params = {
        sessionId: await session //<-- Como es una promesa, haces await
    };

    console.log(params);

}

post();
```

En tu código además tienes que sacar el `.then()`:

```
var session = service.createSession({
    assistantId: "e41c876f-3e71-4c27-a58f-2744227d8d1f",
});

app.post('/conversation/', async (req, res) => {

    const params = { sessionId: await session };

    console.log(params);

});
```